# Why are there only 5 equable triangles with integer value sides?

Tags: geometry

What I mean by this is:

I know there is a process of finding these 5 triangles, but how did the mathematicians prove that there are only 5 of those triangles? As in, why do we know if there are more of those triangle or not?

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle#Equable_triangles) provides references.

Comment: Well, yes, but I looked and the references lead to papers I don’t have access to. I’m just searching for the answer out of pure curiosity.